# No exact matches in call to intializer

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, realm

I have recently shifted to Xcode 12 and start getting error which is not there in the Xcode 11. The Error is related to an Extension which says **No exact matches in call to intializer** Below is the code -

```
public typealias UpdateBlock<T> = (_ object: T?) -> Void

protocol ModelMappeable {
    func map(_ values: JSON, realm: Realm?)
}

extension ModelMappeable where Self: BaseModel {
    
    static func getOrCreate(realm: Realm, values: JSON?, updates: UpdateBlock<Self>?) -> Self {
        var object: Self!
        
        if let primaryKey = values?["_id"].string {
            if let newObject = realm.object(ofType: Self.self, forPrimaryKey: primaryKey as AnyObject) {
                object = newObject
            }
        }

        if object == nil {
            object = self()
        }

        if let values = values {
            object.map(values, realm: realm)
        }

        updates?(object)
        return object
    }

}
```

[image]

[image]

After removing override from initialer get below errors -

[image]

Comment: Does `BaseModel` have a `required` initializer without parameters?

Comment: @Sulthan, No. Please check updated question. I have added images for base model also.

Comment: Please, always add *code*, not *images*. Images are good for additional info but only if you also add the code as text.
Obviously, you cannot create an instance using `Self()` because neither `ModelMappeable` or `BaseModel` contains a `required init()`.

Comment: @Sulthan, What is the solution for this then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide a `required` initializer for `BaseModel` to work around this:

```
class BaseModel: Object {
    @objc dynamic var identifier: String?
    
    required override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}
```

and change:

```
if object == nil {
    object = self()
}
```

in `getOrCreate(realm:values:updates:)` function, to this:

```
if object == nil {
    object = Self()
}
```

**Update**: It turned out that this is not so easy in the previous versions of SwiftRealm.

Specifically you need to override 3 more initializers to accomplish what you want:

```
class BaseModel: Object {
    @objc dynamic var identifier: String?
    
    required init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    override init(value: Any) {
        super.init(value: value)
    }

    required init(realm: RLMRealm, schema: RLMObjectSchema) {
        super.init(realm: realm, schema: schema)
    }

    required init(value: Any, schema: RLMSchema) {
        super.init(value: value, schema: schema)
    }
}
```

Comment: it says's 'override' is implied when overriding a required initializer"

Comment: @VinodSingh I don't see any error on my end. What exact version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: It's Xcode 12.0.1. Not getting any issue in Xcode 11. Only 12 has these issues

Comment: @VinodSingh That's weird. I tested this code in Xcode 12.0.1. So, this is a compilation error?

Comment: Maybe removing `override` will fix it?

Comment: No, getting another errors that says I need to override some other initializer. Please check my question, I have updated it just ow.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223917/discussion-between-vinod-singh-and-gcharita).